# How can you tell (programmatically) if large fonts are in use on a Windows 7 PC

Tags: c++, windows-7, large-fonts

I need to identify whether or not large fonts are in use on Windows 7 from within an app written in C++. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Define large. I know a dude who's fonts are like 2 times bigger than mine, and some people think that mine are big...

Comment: Windows Display Settings: Control Panel / Appearance / Display /...Smaller, Medium, Larger , where Larger = 150%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MFC:

```
void CTestFontDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    int nRes = GetDeviceCaps(*pDC, LOGPIXELSY);
}
```

Normal font size = 96 (100%), medium (125%)= 120...

Answer (score 0):

The Windows display settings (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display) affect the current number of dots per inch (DPI). There is in fact a way to get DPI information [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660.aspx#getting_system_information) using [`GetDeviceCaps()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877.aspx):

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);
int dpiX = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
int dpiY = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

This will give you the DPI in pixels. If you want the actual scale factor (g.e. 150%), divide by 96. 96 is the baseline DPI, so it's considered to be "100%". You can use [MulDiv()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383718.aspx) so the integer division properly rounds the result if needed.

```
int scaleFactorX = ::MulDiv(dpiX, 100, 96);
int scaleFactorY = ::MulDiv(dpiY, 100, 96);
```