# MFC : Font too large on PC but ok on laptop

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, fonts, scaling

I am creating a CFont which is larger than usual :

```
font1.CreateFont(54, 0, 0, 0, FW_HEAVY, false, false, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, 
OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH|FF_MODERN,
_T("Courier New"));
```

And set a CEdit control to use this :

```
m_cEditLimit.SetFont(&font1);
```

This font was showing ok on the laptop when I was writing the app, but now that I am testing on a regular pc it shows too big and won't fit :

[image]

How can I make the font look good on every pc the app is running on ?

Comment: You need to use a font size that adapts to the system settings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268470/calculating-the-logical-font-size

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a hard-coded `54` for the font size, try calculating the size based on points:

```
int points = 32;
pix = -MulDiv(points, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
```

Adjust `points` as necessary until the font fits. Now it should be consistent between systems.